# How to programmatically create tests for TestNG?

Tags: java, automation, testng

I'm writing a library to automate unit test generation for my JPA `@Entity` classes. In short: the user supplies a multimap of field -> values pairs and my library generates tests for them.

Example test data:

```
lastName -> some name, some other name
firstName -> some first name, some other first name
```

Suppose I have a class with tests in it:

```
public class PersonTest
{
    @Test
    public void personNotValidNullLastname() {
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    public void personNotValidTooLongLastname() {
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    public void personNotValidDateofbirth() {
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    public void personValidAddressType() {
       // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

If I execute those tests I get some nice output from the TestNG console:

```
PASSED: personNotValidDateofbirth
PASSED: personNotValidNullLastname
PASSED: personNotValidTooLongLastname
PASSED: personValidAddressType
```

Now I want to create some tests on the fly. If I use the `@Factory` annotation with a method like this:

```
@Factory
public Object[] generateTests() {
    // ...
}
```

This factory creates instances of my custom class:

```
public class EntityFieldTest
{
    // ...

    @Test
    public void doTest()
    {
        testMethod.run(VALIDATOR, entityClass, field, value);
    }
}

// Note that testMethod is an anonymous function parametrized elsewhere
```

It will run all of my generated tests but the output is not saying much:

```
PASSED: doTest
PASSED: doTest
PASSED: doTest
PASSED: doTest
```

How can I execute my test methods to achieve some more verbose result like in `PersonTest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `EntityFieldTest`  implement [`org.testng.ITest`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/ITest.html) and override [`getTestName()`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/ITest.html#getTestName%28%29). You mentioned that you are creating instances of `EntityFieldTest` inside the factory, so provide an `EntityFieldTest` constructor that takes in a string that represents the name of that test. Then return that value in `getTestName()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom logger: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging and generate report that you like.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe you should use some validator classes instead. It's a good idea to want to make sure that core tests have been created, but any energy beyond providing stubs might better be put into classes that actually verify the state of the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [DataProviders](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)?

It will provide you an option to provide data for test cases. You can as well read your test case input from a file and pass on to the test function. Each @Test method need to be annotated with @Dataprovider(name=.., [class=..]

So your personValidAddressType will look like

```
@Test(dataProvider = "validAddressType", dataProviderClass = TestCaseData.class)
public void personValidAddressType(TestCase testCase) {...}
```

In TestCaseData,

```
@DataProvider(name = "validAddressType")
public static Iterator<Object[]> getTestCases() {
    //returns your test case
}
```

Example in the link mentioned was helpful for me in a similar scenario. You also can have a dataprovider returing Object[][] instead of an iterator